# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection Exception

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

I have two application on server one of them spring mvc app and the other one spring boot application run for background tasks like reading data from excel. Two days ago my background app suddenly get this error. The query normally works with milliseconds.

```
2022-03-23 02:07:50,845 INFO  method started
2022-03-23 02:23:39,818 INFO  error : 
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection timed out (Read failed)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:792)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
```

After this error all connections are closed and get this error when try to select from application. When I use sqldeveloper, everything works properly.

```
2022-03-24 08:30:01,540 INFO [Quartz] -  : error:

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatementInternal(PhysicalConnection.java:4079)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:4045)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3951)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
```

In background application I'm connected different schemas in same database. I can work with primary schema's properly. But when try to access second schema always get error above. Spring mvc
app access both schema's without error.

Comment: Hard to say.  How are you configuring access towards both schemas in your Springboot App.  Have you attempted to restart the Spring-boot app to see if it was a connection problem?

Comment: try to execute all these operations under single transactional boundary

Comment: @SMA I started app but still get same error. I’m using spring default configuration settings.